# Ruby: How to parse a string to pull something out and assign it to a variable

Tags: ruby

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
"my name is: andrew"
```

I'd like to parse the string, pull out the name from the string, and assign it to a variable. How would I do this with Ruby?

**Update:**

The string I used as an example was only an example. The strings that I will be working with can change formats, so you can't rely on the colon being in the actual example. Here are a few examples that I'm working with:

```
"/nick andrew"     # command: nick, value: "andrew"
"/join developers" # command: join, value: "developers"
"/leave"           # command: leave, value: nil
```

I'd like to use some sort of regular expression to solve this (since the string can change formats), rather than splitting the string on certain characters or relying on a certain character position number.

Comment: Since you expanded the core question, you should accept one answer in this question and ask another question for your expanded answer.

Comment: There is no magic regular expression that will parse everything. You have to work with a defined grammar.

Comment: You have to have an example of all possible formats of the string so that you can generate a regex to get a specific piece. If you can't provide exact details then you're question is open ended and not able to be answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/ruby-for-newbies-regular-expressions/) really helped me understand how to work with regular expressions in Ruby.

One way to use a regular expression to get the string you want is to replace the stuff you don't want with an empty string.

```
original_string = "my name is: andrew"
name = original_string.sub(/^my name is: /, '') # => 'andrew'

another_format = "/nick andrew"
name = another_format.sub(/^\/nick /, '') # => 'andrew'
```

However, that's just string replacement/substitution. The regex is not capturing anyting.

To capture a string using a regular expression, you can use the Ruby `match` method:

```
original_string = "my name is: andrew"
matches = original_string.match /^my name is: (.*)/
name = matches[1] # return the first match
```

Answer (score 15):

```
s = "my name is: andrew"
p s.split(':')[1].strip # "andrew"
```

See

1. [`split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split)
2. [`strip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-strip)

Answer (score 9):

Another way:

```
name = "my name is: andrew".split(/: */)[1] # => "andrew"
```

or

```
name = "my name is: andrew".split(/: */).last # => "andrew"
```

Breaking it down, first we break it into parts.
The regular expression /: */ says a : followed by any number of spaces will be our splitter.

```
"my name is: andrew".split(/: */) # => ["my name is", "andrew"]
```

Then we select the second item:

```
["my name is", "andrew"][1] # => "andrew"
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do that is:

```
s = "my name is: andrew"
pos = (s =~ /(?!.*:).*/)
result = s[pos..-1]
p result.strip!  # "andrew"
```

Another:

```
s = "my name is: andrew";
p s.slice(s.index(":")..-1) # "andrew"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s.split.last
```

That should work with all of your cases.